# not able to get the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am new to python and just trying to get my way through to Python and I have created a class and created two methods under it but i don't understand why the below code does not work. Any help please?

FYI i am using jupyter notebook

```
class student:
    clg='xyz' #class variable
    def _init_(self,rollno,name):
        self.rollno=rollno
        self.name=name
    def display(self):
        print('student name',self.name)
        print('student roll no',self.rollno)
        print('student college',student.clg)

student1 = student('xyz001',"ajay")
student1.display()
```

### **Error:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-4ae2a2de8a8b> in <module>()
     10         print('student college',student.clg)
     11 
---> 12 student1 = student('xyz001',"ajay")
     13 student1.display()

TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: `_init_` is meant to have a double underscore (dunder), e.g. `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple answer. Your `'_init_'` must have double underscores on either side, like this: `__init__`